# Find the mean and variance of a random variable that is the absolute value of a normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-writing

Let $X \sim \text{Normal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Let $Y = |X|$. Find the pdf of $Y$, as well as $\mathsf E(Y)$ and $\mathsf{Var}(Y)$.

I'm assuming if I can just find the pdf, it'll be simple to find the expected value and variance. I've done method of transformations before, but the absolute value is just throwing me off.

EDIT: I found the pdf to be $\frac 1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac {-(y-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2} + \frac 1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac {-(y+\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}$, which is the folded normal. However, I still cannot figure out how to get $E(Y)$ and $Var(Y)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248334/p-d-f-of-the-absolute-value-of-a-normally-distributed-variable

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Still, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to find E(Y)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: I apologize, but I truly cannot figure out what either of those hints lead to.

Comment: Well, the limits of the integral will change. So, the error function becomes relevant.

Comment: To find the expected value, you can use much of the same approach as I did [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4719791/556297).