# How to compute Harter's integral on article Tables of Range and Studentized Range

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, indefinite-integrals, self-learning, order-statistics

This problem arose while I was teaching Statistical Quality Control at the University to Industrial Engineers, and I asked myself where do the parameters $d_{2}$ and $d_{3}$, used to compute control charts, came from? I did some research and found the article named Tables of Range and Studentized Range by H. Leon Harter https://www.jstor.org/stable/2237810?seq=1.

Page 1124 presents the following equation that was used in order to compute the moments of the range statistics.

$$
E\left(W^{k}\right) = n\left(n-1\right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Bigg\{ \int_{0}^\infty W^{k}  \Big[ \Phi(X+W) - \Phi(X) \Big]^{n-2} \phi(X+W)dW \Bigg\}\phi(X)dx
$$

With

$$
\phi(X) = (2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-X^{2}/2} \qquad \Phi(X) = \int_{0}^X \phi(X)dX
$$

The article itself describes that in order to solve the equation a Lagrangian integration formula was used for the inner integral and the trapezoidal rule for the outer internal. Also mentioned that in the case $n=2$ and $k=1$ the equation has a closed-form with result $E(W) = 2/ (\pi)^{1/2}$

When  the suggested substitutions are made, $n=2$ and $k=1$ ,equation reduces to the following form:

$$
E(W) = 2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Bigg\{ \int_{0}^\infty W (2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{\frac{-(X+W)^{2}}{2}}dW \Bigg\}(2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-X^2/2}dX
$$

I'm guessing, and it looks, that in order to solve this particular case the outer integral looks like the normal integral so, it has to be equal to $1$, if so, the inner integral must have the value of $1/(\pi)^{1/2}$ but it doesn't look like a closed-form or easy to compute.

How to obtain the closed-form for the particular case? and how can you set up the numerical methods in order to solve the equation?

I would appreciate any advice or answers

P.S. If you want to check a reference for the factor for Constructing Variables Control Charts, the book Introduction to Statistical Quality Control 6th edition by Douglas C. Montgomery on page 702
could be checked or I leave the following link http://chafra.bilkent.edu.tr/SOM/Control%20Charts%20Factors.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner integral
$$
 \int_{0}^\infty W  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(X+W)^{2}}{2}}dW  
$$

can be solved by employing the substitution $Z = X + W$, and we get

$$\begin{align*}\int_{0}^\infty W  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(X+W)^{2}}{2}}dW  
&= \int_{X}^\infty (Z - X) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-Z^{2}}{2}}dZ \\ &= \int_{X}^\infty Z \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-Z^{2}}{2}}dZ -
   X \int_{X}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-Z^{2}}{2}}dZ \\
&=\frac{e^{-0.5X^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} -  X(1 - \Phi(X))  \\
&=\phi(X) - X\Phi(-X)
\end{align*}$$

Where $\phi(x)$ and $\Phi(x)$ are respectively the PDF and CDF of a standard normal variable.

The outer integral is simply 2 times the expectation of the inner integral, with $X$ a standard normal variable:

$$\begin{align*} E[W] &= 2E[\phi(X)] - 2E[X \Phi(-X)] \\
                      &= 2E[\phi(X)] + 2E[X \Phi(X)] \end{align*}$$

Using [Stein's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4788282/how-to-find-ex-phix-with-x-normally-distributed), we have $E[X \Phi(X)] = E[\phi(X)]$, and so

$$\begin{align*}E[W] &= 4E[\phi(X)] \\ &= \frac{4}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-X^2}dX \\
&= \frac{4}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Hi Guillaume, So many topics I didn't know, for example, folded normal distribution. And there's a lot of information about Gaussian integral for the one who knows where to search. I have some questions, hope you'll have the time to clarify

a) How did you realize that the mean for the folded normal was $\mu = -X$ and not $\mu = W$

b) What happened with the W right after the integration sign?