# How to find $E[X \Phi(X)]$ with $X$ normally distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X$ be distributed as a standard normal variable, with CDF $\Phi(x)$.

How do I prove that $E[X \Phi(X)] = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$?

That is, how to show that

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} X \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-0.5X^2}\int^{X}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-0.5Z^2}dZdX = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} $$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @JoseAvilez Routine application of steins lemma, which if they are asking, they definitely do not know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Stein's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_lemma), we have

$$E[g(X) X] = E[g'(X)]$$

Using $g(x) = \Phi(x), g'(x) = \phi(x)$,

$$\begin{align*}E[\Phi(X)X] = E[\phi(X)] &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-X^2}dX \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}}
\end{align*}$$