# What happens if you forbid negative values in Gaussian distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I use a random number generator to generate normally distributed numbers. The problem is negative numbers are unphysical in that particular simulation. So I use "if/else" to discard them.

My question is: What is the resulting distribution? It's obviously not Gaussian any more since it is cut on the left.

Comment: You can use the absolute value of the normal distribution, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248334/p-d-f-of-the-absolute-value-of-a-normally-distributed-variable/1248608#1248608)

Comment: This will make it even more distorted (unless the mean of my original distribution is far away, on the right).

Comment: @user373714 The analytical expression for your distribution is just a gaussian multiplied by two for normalization, with positive $x$. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @RicardoMM That would be the case if the mean of the original distribution was zero, right? It is not. The mean is some positive number.

Comment: @user373714 That's true. But it will be always biased if you cut off the negative values.

Comment: @callculus42 Exactly. Please read my original question. What it says is exacrly what I am interested in. Nothing else. And it is very preceisely formulated.

Comment: @user373714 To answer your question: Yes, the resulting distribution is not normally distributed anymore. I hope this answer is more helpful ;-)

Comment: @callculus42 Thank you. Now my question is: What is this distribution? If there is previous work on this (I would be amazed if there weren't) - could someone please provide a reference. If not - I will sit down and derive it myself.

Comment: @user373714  It is not clear what you want, thus I have no reference. Sorry.

Comment: @callculus42 I want either a name for the resulting distribution (if there is a name) or the formula (if there is an analytical formula for it). Like for Gaussian distribution we have the name "Gaussian" or "normal". For Pareto we have the name "Pareto". And so on. And also we have equations that describe these distributions. For instance, for Gaussian we have exp etc. I would like to see something like this for the distribution that is obtained by discarding negative values in the Gaussian (in the general case where the mean of the original Gaussian is positive).

Comment: I put my money on red in roulette, and forbid black. Made no difference. Lost it all.

Comment: More interesting trivia than an answer, this distribution is a solution to the Quantum Harmonic Oscillator Schrodinger Equation where the wave function is zero for negative values of x.  This has interesting implications for the expectation values of the moments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you search for [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) you will find what you want.

In your particular case, the density function is given by

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{{\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)}}{1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)}$$

where $\phi$ is the standard normal density:

$$\phi(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}z^2\right)$$

and where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution.

Comment: The last comment by the question poster indicated they wanted a reference. I have provide a reference (the linked Wikipedia article).

Comment: Now THAT was helpful. Thank you very much!